# which collection class is efficient for insertion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, generics, collections

If i want to insert the data in these collection class "Dictionary","List" and "Sorted List" which will required the less time to perform the insertion? can you give give me a code to explain that process?

Comment: Either `Dictionary` or `LinkedList` should have good insertion characteristics.  Do you want "code" or an explanation?

Comment: Dictionary and List are very different.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Dictionary? I can't think of a much worse collection for pure insertion. Why not `List` or another unsorted container?

Comment: @Ben thank you for your answer, could you please tell me how can i test these performance? if you can give me an example in code

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you said what the application was for rather than ask which has faster insertion times. There are many more considerations to which data structure is correct to use, such as insertion time, lookup time, memory it takes, etc.

Comment: @jalf: Hash tables and linked lists have `O(1)` (amortized in the case of the hash table) insertion, while `List` has `O(N)`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `O(n)`? How? There's no criteria for *where* the object should be inserted, so you can just insert at the end, which is amortized constant time (and with lower constant overhead than for a hash table)

Comment: @jalf: Maybe it's just the choice of words. In my vocabulary, that's an *append*, not an *insert*.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you want to insert between elements (not simply add a new one without taking care of where in regard to other elements), `Dictionary` is indeed a wrong, buggy choice. Enumeration order over a dictionary is [undefined](/a/1453210/1178314). So it does not make sens to try insert an element between others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a value to LinkedList is O(1) operation. List (implemented by an array) may require additional allocation and copying of items.

Comment: It is O(1) provided a reference to an adjacent node is already held. The linked list maintain references to `First` and `Last` node. If the insert has to happen in the middle of the list, without already knowing which node is adjacent before or after the insert position, then it requires to skip through half of the list to reach the target node, and it is no more an O(1) operation.(But at worst an "O(n/2)" which we should simply write O(n).)

Comment: @Frédéric Needing to find an unreferenced member is a lookup, and it's not special to linked lists.  For example, if you don't know the index of a member in an array, you still have to loop through the array looking for it.

Answer (score 13):

`List<T>` will have the fastest insertion.
`LinkedList<T>` will have the fastest insertion *at the head*.

The difference will be miniscule for most practical applications; you should use whichever one fits your needs.

Comment: `List<T>` has fast (amortized `O(1)`) *append*, but terrible *insertion* performance.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `List<T>` still needs to resize its array periodically.

Comment: That's why append is `O(1)` amortized, not `O(1)` for every insert.

Comment: I know.  That's why LinkedList is faster for head insertion.

Comment: `LinkedList` has lower complexity for insertion anywhere except at the end, because with `List` all later elements have to be moved to make space.  And that cost isn't amortized.  But it has nothing to do with resizing the array.

Comment: The first line of this answer needs to be fixed; `List<T>` does _not_ have a fast insert.  BenVoigt already made this point, but this answer's gotten a lot of up-votes anyway, which is just strange.

Comment: The last line should be fixed, too, because the difference isn't small in relative terms.  Since inserting into a `List<T>` is O(_n_) while inserting into a `LinkedList<T>` is O(1), the loss of performance is basically linear with the number of members in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

If your performance requirements are strict, you should **measure** in your environment and on *your data* before deciding.

I'll offer some guesses that you should not take for granted until you perform your own measurements:

- If you know the number of elements in advance, just use the
  pre-allocated `List` (or array).
- If you don't:

  - Use list of chunks (i.e. `LinkedList<List<T>>`) to avoid `List` resizes.
  - Or, for simplicity, you can just use the `List` and incur some
    performance penalty when it is resized to accept more elements. I'm
    not sure whether this penalty would justify using `Dictionary` or `LinkedList`
    instead - but you will be if you measure ;)

All this is under assumption you don't care *where* in the collection is new element inserted and how you retrieve it later... If you **do** care, then you'll pick your data structure based on *that*, and not just insert performance alone.